# Trouble filtering potentiometer data (noisy, high spikes)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, filter, sensors, noise

I've collected some data from a potentiometer using an Arduino microcontroller. Here is the data which was sampled at 500 Hz (it's a lot of data):

http://cl.ly/3D3s1U3m1R1T?_ga=1.178935463.2093327149.1426657579

If you zoom in you can see that essentially I have a pot that just rotates back and forth i.e., I should see a linear increase and then a linear decrease. While the general shape of the data affirms this, almost every single time there's some really freaking annoying (sometimes surprisingly wide) spikes that get in the way of a really nice shape. Is there any way I can make some type of algorithm or filter which fixes this? I tried a median filter, and using the percentiles but neither worked. I mean I feel like it shouldn't be the hardest thing because I can clearly see what it should look like-basically the minimum of where the spikes occur-but for some reason everything I try miserably fails or at least looses the integrity of the original data.

I'd appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: A low pass filter ought to be able to sort this out.  Transform to frequency space using FFT, filter out high frequencies, and transform back to time domain.

Comment: ditto on the filter. you could filter in the time domain, or frequency domain as @duffymo mentioned.

Comment: OK so I know how to transform into the frequency domain (just use the fft function right?) but how do I implement the low pass filter? What steps should I take? I want to get the best looking data possible.

Comment: In the time domain, should I do a moving average to act as a low pass filter (or is there something better)?

Comment: Your link is now broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle your problem. However none of them will ever be perfect. I'll give you 2 approaches here.

### Moving average (*low pass filter*)

In Matlab, one easy way to "low pass" filter your data without having to explicitly use FFT, is to use the `filter` function` (available in the base package, you do not need any specific toolbox).

You create a kernel for the filter, and apply it twice (once in each direction), to cancel the phase shift introduced. This is in effect a "Moving Average" filter with zero phase shift.
The size (length) of the kernel will control how heavy the averaging process will be.

So for example, 2 different filter lengths:

```
n = 100 ; %// length of the filter
kernel = ones(1,n)./n ;
q1 = filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(p) ) ;  %// apply the filter in one direction
q1 = filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(q1) ) ; %// re-apply in the opposite direction to cancel phase shift

n = 500 ; %// length of the filter
kernel = ones(1,n)./n ;
q2 = filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(p) )) ) ; %// same than above in one line
```

Will produce on your data:
[image: denoising1]

As you can see, each filter size has its pros and cons. The more you filter, the more of your spikes you cancel, but the more you deform your original signal. It is up to you to find your optimum settings.

---

### 2) Search derivative anomalies

This is a different approach. You can observe on your signal that the spikes are mostly sudden, it means the change of value of your signal is rapid, and luckily faster than the "normal" rate of change of your desired signal. It means that you can calculate the derivative of your signal, and identify all the spikes (the derivative will be much higher than for the rest of the curve).
Since this only identify the "beginning" and "end" of the spikes (not the occasional plateau in the middle), we will need to extend a little bit the zone identified as faulty by this method.
When the identification of faulty data is done, you just discard these data points and re-interpolate your curve over the original interval (taking support on the points you have left).

```
%% // Method 2 - Reinterpolation of cancelled data

%// OPTIONAL slightly smooth the initial data to get a cleaner derivative
n = 10 ; kernel = ones(1,n)./n ;
ps = filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(filter( kernel , 1 , fliplr(p) )) ) ;

%// Identify the derivative anomalies (too high or too low)
dp = [0 diff(ps)] ;             %// calculate the simplest form of derivative (just the difference between consecutive points)
dpos = dp >= (std(dp)/2) ;      %// identify positive derivative above a certain threshold (I choose the STD but you could choose something else)
dneg = dp <= -(std(dp)/2) ;     %// identify negative derivative above the threshold
ixbad = dpos | dneg ;           %// prepare a global vector of indices to cancel

%// This will cancel "nPtsOut" on the RIGHT of each POSITIVE derivative
%// point identified, and "nPtsOut" on the LEFT of each NEGATIVE derivative
nPtsOut = 100 ;                 %// decide how many points after/before spikes we are going to cancel
for ii=1:nPtsOut
    ixbad = ixbad | circshift( dpos , [0 ii]) | circshift( dneg , [0 -ii]) ;
end

%// now we just reinterpolate the missing gaps
xp = 1:length(p) ;                              %// prepare a base for reinterpolation
pi = interp1( xp(~ixbad) , p(~ixbad) , xp )  ;  %// do the reinterpolation
```

This will produce:
[image: denoising1]

The red signal is the result of the above moving average, the green signal is the result of the derivative approach.
There are also settings you can change to adjust this result (the threshold for the derivative, 'nPtsOut' and even the initial smoothing of the data).

As you can see, for the same amount of spike cancellation than the moving average method, it respect a bit more the integrity of the initial data.  However it is not perfect either and some interval will still be deformed. But as I said at the beginning, no method is ever perfect.

Comment: Wow. Absolutely fantastic. I learned so much from this post. Thank you so much for taking the time to show me this. Also, while you point out that the second method isn't perfect, it's still DAMN good. 
You'r amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have large spikes near the maximum and minimum points of you pot. You can limit the range of your valid data between 200 and 300 for instance.

Another option is a 1st order low pass filter like this one

```
alpha = 0.01 %parameter to tune!

p_filtered(1) = p(1);
for i=2:length(p)
    p_filtered(i) = alpha*p(i) + (1-alpha)* p_filtered(i-1);
end
```

Comment: Seems like it's worth a try. Also, it's interesting that you point out that the spikes peak near the max/min of the pot. I may have to investigate why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The noise spikes are being caused by the POT’s wiper bouncing along the resistive track as the knob is turned. This is a common problem with them. In future you should look at adding a 0.1uF capacitor to the POT output and this should fix the problem.

With your current data the simplest option is to just do a simple moving average and visually tune the number of samples averaged until the spikes are sufficiently suppressed while not affecting the underlying data. Note that a moving average is just a low pass filter with a [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter) frequency response.

The normal way to post-process this sort of data is to do an FFT (using an appropriate windowing function), zero out the noise values above the signal of interest and then take an inverse FFT. This is also just lowpass filtering (with a sinc * windowing function weighted moving average), but you use the insight provided by the FFT to select your cutoff frequency. If you’re not comfortable with the maths involved in doing this then just go with the simple moving average filter. It should be fine for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using a capacitor. I'm going to go ahead ans try and will let you know what the results look like. However, I'm interested in learning more about a "sinc frequency response." What do you mean by sinc? I wasn't able to understand your last paragraph because of that.
Either way, thanks.

Comment: and try that*...woops

Comment: See added link. A moving average filter has a sin(x) / x frequency response. You can see from the shape that this is not a particularly high performance filter, however it is simple. The last bit was trying to explain how a moving average filter is just a special case of a general digital filter and how you could use the FFT to do the filtering instead. Sorry but I don't currently have a matlab license so can't show you any results.

Comment: That's OK, I appreciate it. I still want to learn about it so I'm glad you edited. I'm actually just hoping that adding the capacitor will solve the issue at hand, and I can try to salvage this data by using what Hoki showed as much as possible.